# jquery unbind to override onsubmit in a form submission

Tags: jquery, webforms, submit

This is the form declaration:

```
      <form id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="this.action='/mis_apps/scholarships-syste'+'m/index.cfm/scholarships/edit';">
```

This my javascript:

```
     $("#form1").attr("action", "/mis_apps/scholarships-syste'+'m/index.cfm/scholarships/test");
     alert($("#form1").attr("action"));
     $("#form1").unbind("submit").submit();
```

The alert correct displays the new action. But when submit is ran, it still goes to the original code in the onsubmit.

I also tried:

```
    $("#form1").unbind("submit");
    $("#form1").submit();
```

But it still doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.unbind` will remove only jQuery attached event handlers.

Try this,

```
$('#form1').removeAttr('onsubmit')
$('#form1').submit();
```

You can test it here, http://jsfiddle.net/k5Tnh/3/